# Dual boot Lubuntu install not going well. (on old P4 w/ xp)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, lubuntu

Have an unallocated partition, (Youtube vid), Have the 16.04iso on usb. Several different versions all crashed, or just didn't load from the usb.

Can't write code, so if it's not fully auto-install, I will have trouble.
Tried the32bit iso, then the alternate one, and then the live boot, I can't get it to boot from my USB.
Got passed the boot sequence telling it to boot from USB, but it just sits there, curser blinking. 
Tried the automatic one with grub too. No go.

Anyone care to help a retard? Barely know enough html to post comments on a forum. Past that I'm clueless.

Comment: How did you create the Ubuntu USB drive? You can't just copy the ISO file to USB like a normal file -- you need to use `dd` or Rufus or Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: If it's an old P4 machine, it probably doesn't even having USB booting capabilities unless it's ZIP or floppy formatted -- even then, though, I doubt it. USB booting didn't become anything close to a standard feature until around 2005, maybe later. If it does allow booting from USB, you're going to have to find a way to format the USB drive as a giant floppy (floppy formatting) or ZIP drive (zip formatting). I'll see if I can dig up some information on how to do those properly and if Ubuntu can even be installed in those circumstances. I won't be as easy as using a tool like Unetbootin though.

Comment: First tried LiveLinux. It doesn't work with xp. Then Unetbootin, and a couple other that create a bootable usb.

Maybe I didn't prepare the USB correctly?

Yes, it can be booted from USB, and recognizes mine ok.

Operating System
 MS Windows XP Professional 32-bit SP3
CPU
 Intel Pentium 4 516
 Prescott 90nm Technology
RAM
 3.00 GB Single-Channel @ 133MHz
Motherboard
 ASUSTeK Computer INC. Goldfish3 (CPU 1) 139 °F
Graphics
 DELL M770 (1280x1024@60Hz)
 Intel(R) 82915G/GV/910GL Express Chipset Family
.

Comment: The online self help guides are incomplete for a newb.
Formatted usb in fat32 Now tring pendrive.
Most advice says only Lubuntu will work on an oldie like mine. So, that's what I have focused on.

Comment: It appears your machine is simply incapable of running Ubuntu, as described by @ChuckR

Answer (score 0):

Use a CD or DVD instead. If you don't have a DVD drive, download and install from the mini.iso instead.

[Click here to download the mini.iso](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso)

[Click here for more info on installing using this method.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall)

[Click here for more info on how to burn a CD or DVD.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

If you insist on using a USB, you should use the [Universal Pendrive Linux installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).

[Or click here to download.](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/Universal-USB-Installer/Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.4.exe)

Using the universal pendrive linux program, do not select the distro using the program from the list and do select the iso from file instead and use the mini.iso.

Comment: Thanks. Will give this a try too. I'm sure that I'm just leaving out some crucial step(s). Can't succeed if I don't stumble a bit.

I'll try pendrive.

No cd burning software since new xp pro and HD upgrade.

Not insisting on a usb. Thought it was the only way to install w/o a cd.

Just want to install Lubuntu, and be able to dual boot either XP or Lubuntu and learn something about Linux before getting a machine running solely on linux.

usb boot option works
I know I'm just leaving out steps/files... 
Nothing but time so thanks for the answers. Trying them now.

Comment: Ran Speccy to get this info...

Operating System
 MS Windows XP Professional 32-bit SP3
CPU
 Intel Pentium 4 516
 Prescott 90nm Technology
RAM
 3.00 GB Single-Channel @ 133MHz
Motherboard
 ASUSTeK Computer INC. Goldfish3 (CPU 1) 139 °F
Graphics
 DELL M770 (1280x1024@60Hz)
 Intel(R) 82915G/GV/910GL Express Chipset Family

Didn't need XP Pro. Lost disk that came with computer for restore. Pro was the cheapest $$ online, so I got it, and installed it on a bigger HD.

Comment: Noticed that it requires a MBR partition. That's probably what's holding me up. Gotta go look up how to do that first.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Giving up. Will order a usb or cd to solve my prob.
Thot I could build a bootable usb and dual boot the machine. Guess not.